# How to find duplicate case insensitive records in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a user table with the fields `id` and `email` (among others). The email address isn't case insensitive, a problem we want to fix, but we have some duplicate values in there (duplicate except the case, so currently we have `user@example.com` and `User@example.com` in there). I am now trying to get an overview of all the duplicate accounts, but this query is just taking forever, I had to cancel it after 5 minutes. The table has about 250.000 records.

```
select * from user u1
where (select count(*) from user u2
where LOWER(u1.email) = LOWER(u2.email)) > 1
```

I am finding plenty of examples to find literal duplicate records, but nothing for case-insensitive duplicates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `having` clause. Should be faster than the inner clause

```
select lower(email) 
from test 
group by lower(email) 
having count(*)>1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/VNcSzfZp)